# rails 3 access to model and mailer from external script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

As in topic how i can access model and mailer from ruby script? I want to do some thinks which are not web related and can't be done via rails but are bound to database used in rails. For eg. i want to check when sb premium ends and 7 days before sand him email.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a rake task which you can call and check the output of.

In `lib/tasks/appname.rake`

```
task :do_some_stuff => :environment do
  # any code you want in here.
  puts "some output"
end
```

You can then call it from the command line with

```
rake do_some_stuff
```